# WordPress database error table doesn't exist

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I'm developing a new Wordpress site (http://citylovesearch.com) and all was going well until I updated to the latest version of BuddyPress.

Here is the server error log.  I think we hit the host's memory limit, resulting in tables not being created. Now I'm struggling to access the website. What's the best way to add/fix this?

> [29-Aug-2015 08:45:17 UTC] WordPress database error Table 'citylove_clsdb.wp_cls_bp_album' doesn't exist for query SELECT DISTINCT  COUNT(id) AS count FROM wp_cls_bp_album WHERE 1 = 1 AND privacy <= 0  made by require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), do_action('init'), call_user_func_array, bp_init, do_action('bp_init'), call_user_func_array, bp_setup_globals, do_action('bp_setup_globals'), call_user_func_array, bp_album_setup_globals, bp_album_query_pictures, BP_Album_Template->__construct, bp_album_get_picture_count, BP_Album_Picture::query_pictures
>
> [29-Aug-2015 08:45:17 UTC] WordPress database error Table 'citylove_clsdb.wp_cls_bp_album' doesn't exist for query SELECT * FROM wp_cls_bp_album WHERE 1 = 1 AND privacy <= 0 ORDER BY id ASC  made by require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), do_action('init'), call_user_func_array, bp_init, do_action('bp_init'), call_user_func_array, bp_setup_globals, do_action('bp_setup_globals'), call_user_func_array, bp_album_setup_globals, bp_album_query_pictures, BP_Album_Template->__construct, bp_album_get_pictures, BP_Album_Picture::query_pictures

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What other plugins are you using?  It looks like you're trying to use "BuddyPress Album", a 3rd party plugin (not BuddyPress). If so, that plugin hasn't been updated in years; it would be surprising if it still works.

Comment: If you can't access wp-admin try connecting with sftp/ssh and delete all plugin files.  Then reinstall the plugins one at a time checking the site as each you install each one.

Comment: Don't delete all plugin files. First try using FTP to rename the plugin folder for BuddyPress Album. That will deactivate that plugin. And then you should be able to access wp-admin.